# Module.Exports not working for Express

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I'm trying to organize routes in express. But I'm having trouble getting a simple setup to work. I have two files, *api.js*, which has the routing info, and *index.js*, which runs the server.

However, when I try this, I get no response on localhost:3000.

**api.js**

```
var express = require('express');

module.exports = function() {
  var router = express.Router();
  router.get('/', function(req, res) {
    res.send('im the home page!');  
  });
  return router;  
}
```

**index.js**

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();

var router = require('./api');

app.use('/',router);
app.listen(3000);
console.log('Listening on port 3000!');
```

However, when I change *api.js* to this, it works:

**api.js**

```
var express = require('express');

var router = express.Router();
router.get('/', function(req, res) {
  res.send('im the home page!');  
});

module.exports = router;
```

I don't understand why the bottom api.js works when the top one doesn't. Shouldn't module.exports return the same express Router in both cases?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The difference is that in the first version you're exporting a function that *returns* the router vs the second version where you're *exporting* the router itself.

In the first version, Express calls your exported function, passing it `req` and `res`, expecting it to somehow handle the request. The exported function of course is not designed to handle a request (it's just creating a router and returning it), so the request times out.